# Module parse failed? I need help setting up Babel

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I'm writing my first JavaScript library and I'm testing it locally with a React project. I'm not seeing any Typescript errors when I'm writing my code but when I run `yarn start` for the React project that it linked to I'm getting the following error:

```sh
ERROR in ../test-lib/src/add.ts 3:29

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:29)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.runtime = require('/home/aaron/projects/react-projects/test-app/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js');
| 
> export default function add(a: number, b: number) {
|   return a + b
| }
```

I edited this question to simplify the problem after I did some research - which is it looks like I need to compile the typescript code in my library and export it to a `dist` folder? Then the React app that depends on it can use it.

I'm seeing articles about **Babel** and ones about **Rollup** and I'm confused about which I need (or both?) and why. Lots of outdated and incomplete/lazy tutorial articles that don't seem to help.

Can you help me set up what I need to get this to work? Here is the current file structure of my test library, `test-lib`:

```sh
node_modules/
src/
  add.ts
  index.js
package.json
tsconfig.ts
yarn.lock
```

Here are the contents of the pertinent files:

**src/add.ts**:

```js
export default function add(a: number, b: number) {
  return a + b
}
```

**src/index.js**:

```js
import add from './add'
export default add
```

**package.json**:

```json
{
  "name": "test-lib",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**tsconfig.json**:

```json
{
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

I'm aware I'll have to install `@babel/...` packages and the plugin for `@babel/preset-typescript` but I've left this out in the example because I wanted a freshly untouched typescript library for simplicity's sake. Help me start from scratch here.

I have additional questions as well:

- Can I have all my files in `*.ts` format or does the entry point need to be a javascript file? (I'm assuming any `*.config.*` files probably need to be `*.js` as you need to start with javascript first so you can set up typescript for the rest of the project, right?
- I've heard that I should compile my code for `commonjs` as well as `esnext`. Does my choice affect the needed libraries or steps to run their React app by the user that depends on my library?
- The library I'm writing depends on React but it won't have any `jsx/tsx` files. It will have some custom React hooks though. Do I need to include the `@babel/preset-react` plugin as well?

Comment: please add Webpack config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Rollup` or `Webpack` are module bundler and they handle files bundling only.
To transpile Javascript latest code to browser compatible code, we need transpilers like babel. There are plugins available for `Rollup` and `Webpack` to handle this transpiling of code, `Babel` is such a plugin.

So Babel and Rollup are different tools, we can use Babel inside Rollup for transpiling of Javascript.

Let's take `Webpack` as bundler for your questions

**What about typescript ?**

We need some plugin to convert it into js, there are plugins like `ts-loader` for `Webpack`

**What about entry point ?**

You can use ts or js, it does not matter as module bundler will assign each file to it's corresponding plugin to handle based on the `Webpack` configuration during bundling.

**Can I have all my files in *.ts format or does the entry point need to be a javascript file?...**

Yes, you can have all files in .ts. You may need .tsx if you have jsx code.

**I've heard that I should compile my code for commonjs as well as esnext...**

Yes, it will affect the user as their browser can be old and will not support latest code.

**The library I'm writing depends on React but it won't have any jsx/tsx files**...

Do you have jsx code?, if yes then you will need this.

*Note: If your full code is in typescript, you do not need babel, you can simply use `ts-loader` following below link.*

You may want to follow this simple `Webpack` config for typescript - https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/

Comment: Your link led me to this which looks like a full example of a Typescript library: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/tree/main/examples/vanilla

I may have other questions about `npm pack` and making sure I'm only packing the files I want. I'll probably make a separate post about this and link it here if you'd like to help answer those questions. Thanks.